# Having difficulty with DataGridView hyperlink on c# and ms accesss

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagridview, ms-access-2007, datagridviewlinkcolumn

I have winform in c# that contains datagridview that display table from my database. One of the column is hyperlink data type. But the link doesn't seem to display correctly. for example http://google.com display as #http://google.com# on the column. The question is:
How do I remove # from my hyperlink column?
How can I make the link accessible? I mean, whenever I click, the link opens in a browser. Here is the example [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBUrF.jpg)

Comment: Are the pound characters in the database?  Should they be in the database? Maybe the issue is the code the incorrectly put the pounds in the database.

Comment: Check your database how the links are stored. As for the second part of your question, please check [How to handle the click event of DataGridViewLinkColumn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13011407/how-to-handle-the-click-event-of-datagridviewlinkcolumn), Good luck.

Comment: I checked the database and the link is okay, there are no # sign there. I guess it has problem with the data type, because it is hyperlink on Microsoft access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the link column separately.

I write a working code example, and you could have a look.

Code:

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataGridViewLinkColumn col1 = new DataGridViewLinkColumn();
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(col1);
            dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "Links";

            DataGridViewRow dgvr = new DataGridViewRow();
            dgvr.CreateCells(dataGridView1);

            DataGridViewCell linkCell = new DataGridViewLinkCell();
            linkCell.Value = @"http:\\www.google.com";
            dgvr.Cells[0] = linkCell;

            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(dgvr);
        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewLinkColumn && !(e.RowIndex == -1))
            {
                Process.Start(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I actually have finally figured it out. The actual problem is on the database and it had fixed.