# why can't my datagridview delete from datagridviewcolumnlink with event CellContentClick in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

why can't my datagridview delete from datagridviewcolumnlink with event CellContentClick in vb.net?

I want to delete the selected rows with datagridview column link.
I tried to click in the link column there was no event whatsoever but if I tried with the button event then it worked as the code below

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count = 0 Then
            Return
        End If
        If MessageBox.Show("Delete selected record?", "CONFIRM!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel) = DialogResult.Yes Then

            For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.SelectedRows
                DataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(row.Index)
            Next row
        End If
    End Sub
```

is there something wrong with my code please guide me

Thanks

```
 Private table1 As New DataTable
    Public Property AllowDelete() As Boolean = True
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        table1.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Column1", GetType(String)))
        table1.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Column2", GetType(String)))
        table1.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Column3", GetType(String)))
        table1.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Column4", GetType(String)))
        table1.Rows.Add("1", "1", "1", "X")
        table1.Rows.Add("2", "2", "2", "X")
        table1.Rows.Add("3", "3", "3", "X")
        table1.Rows.Add("4", "4", "4", "X")
        DataGridView1.ReadOnly = True
        DataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect
        ColDel.Visible = Me.AllowDelete
        DataGridView1.AllowUserToDeleteRows = ColDel.Visible
        DataGridView1.DataSource = table1

    End Sub
 Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick
        If e.ColumnIndex = ColDel.Index Then

            If DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count = 0 Then
                Return
            End If
            If MessageBox.Show("Delete selected record?", "CONFIRM!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel) = DialogResult.Yes Then

                For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.SelectedRows
                    DataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(row.Index)
                Next row
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: You need still an delete  command, ideally build with a commambuilder

Comment: @nbk , `You need still an delete command, ideally build with a commambuilder` how can I do this please guide me?

Comment: Sorry I thought that you had a database, so need to update the datagridviewb

Comment: @nbk , Yes, that's fine, but why if I use the button event, I can delete it in the DataGridView while the column link has no event if I click the content, is there something wrong with the sample code that I posted

Comment: Why would you be using a link column to do anything related to selected rows? That makes no sense. You should be acting on only the row that the user clicked on, which you can determine using the e.ColumnIndex property.

Comment: @jmcilhinney , I've given an answer in this post if something is wrong so I can fix it. Please recommend me

Comment: My recommendation is to make your UI work properly. If a user clicks a link in a row, it should act on that row only.

Comment: @jmcilhinney , `If e.ColumnIndex = 3 Then` I made it like this

Comment: My apologies. I said ColumnIndex when I meant RowIndex. You would test the ColumnIndex first, to make sure that it is the link column that was clicked, then you would use the RowIndex to get the row that was clicked and act on that specifically.

Comment: @jmcilhinney , Yes it's okay, thanks for your response. Means the answer from me is correct?

Comment: No, the answer is wrong because you're still using SelectedRows. I will post answer when I'm at my PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in the comment, use `e.ColumnIndex` to make sure the cell that the event was raised for is in the correct column and then use `e.RowIndex` to get the row to remove:

```vb
If e.ColumnIndex = 3 Then
    DataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(e.RowIndex)
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

In accordance with this link solution  [How to handle the click event of DataGridViewLinkColumn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13011407/how-to-handle-the-click-event-of-datagridviewlinkcolumn)

```
 Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick
        If e.ColumnIndex = 3 Then

            If DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count = 0 Then
                Return
            End If
            If MessageBox.Show("Delete selected record?", "CONFIRM!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel) = DialogResult.Yes Then

                For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.SelectedRows
                    DataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(row.Index)
                Next row
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```